# Parallel requests in httpurlconnection

Tags: java, http, web

How to get data about parallel requests (those requests that we see in the network field in the browser) using HttpURLConnection java?

It is possible?

Comment: No. Why do you think you need this? The network isn't multi-threaded.

Comment: @user207421 Good. I need this to get all requests from the "Network" field from DevTools (browser). I thought it's possible without using selenium. I used selenium and realized that I can only send get requests, but I need to send others as well.

Comment: Sure but why parallel requests? That's what I asked about. That's what *you* asked about.

Comment: @user207421
Yes, sorry. I got you, it's my mistake
These request is not parallel, they going in order
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when a basic resource such as an html page is called, it has notations in its markup and javascript to e.g. images , scripts and other "resources" by their locations. So at the top of the tree of resources to be used is the html page and the initial http request with the sub sequent to resources caled from their individual locations.
You would require to query the browser about the page not the embedded java applet and that threabout would make it a user installed application for security purposes anyhow.

Comment: Thanks. 
As I understood, these requests can only be received using the browser or by emulating it? For example, using selenium.